# How to assign multiple pools to single virtual server [VIP] in F5

Tags: f5-big-ip

I have a requirement in F5 where i have to configure multiple pools and all pools will be using Single virtual server [1 VIP] to receive traffic from outside world. I am trying to figure out any specific configuration is required which i am missing to achieved this goal. As of now my F5 config is working when i assign default pool to virtual server , since i have to use 1 VIP with multiple clients hosted on it so i am stuck at this point. can someone help me here.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? Did you need more information, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to use iRules in order to have multiple pools on a single VIP. 
See relevant documentation [here](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/irules-101-05-selecting-pools-pool-members-and-nodes)

The thing you have to think about now is how to select which pool to use. You could check the host or URI values as follow :

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [HTTP::uri] contains "blabla"} {
    pool "Your pool name here"
 }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information, am quite familiar with F5 iRules ;)

Comment: irule is one solution to it agreed. This will create problem in near future when we create 100s of pools and every time we have to update irule. I have used host based irule to route the traffic , any idea if we can write common irule across the platform to serve the purpose or any specific config we can do to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Dexirian is correct above - but I think this more correctly answers based on your need for multiple pools due to multiple clients:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
    switch -glob [string tolower [HTTP::uri]] {
        "/123*" { 
            HTTP::uri "/"
            pool pool_123 
        }
        "/456*" { 
            HTTP::uri "/"
            pool pool_456 
        }
        "/789*" { 
            HTTP::uri "/"
            pool pool_789 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are switching pool by application name (read: fqdn) then you could name your pools appropriately and the iRule could be generic:

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if { [catch {pool [HTTP::host]}] } {
    log local0. "error - pool [HTTP::host] does not exist"
    # Set pool to default since HTTP::host did not match existing pool
    pool [LB::server pool]
  }
}
```